# Decide whether the following statements are true or false. If true, prove it. If false, provide a counterexample

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Decide whether the following statements are true or false. If true, prove it. If false, provide a counterexample

If $h: A → B$, $g: B → C$ and $f: B → C$ are three functions, and $(g\circ h) = (f\circ h)$ , then $f = g$.

Comment: Hint: What if $h$ is not onto (e.g. constant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False. Let $A=B=C=\mathbb{R}$. Let $f(x)=x^{2}$ and $g(x)=x^{3}$. Take $h(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then $g\circ h=f\circ h=0$ for all $x$. But $f$ and $g$ are clearly not the same.